# Array values into string

Tags: php

I've been searching and searching and can't find anything that works, but this is what I want to do.

This code:

```
try{
$timeout = 2;
$scraper = new udptscraper($timeout);
$ret = $scraper->scrape('udp://tracker.openbittorrent.com:80',array('0D7EA7F06E07F56780D733F18F46DDBB826DCB65'));
print_r($ret);
}catch(ScraperException $e){
echo('Error: ' . $e->getMessage() . "<br />\n");
echo('Connection error: ' . ($e->isConnectionError() ? 'yes' : 'no') . "<br />\n");
}
```

Outputs this:

```
Array ( [0D7EA7F06E07F56780D733F18F46DDBB826DCB65] => Array ( [seeders] => 148 [completed] => 10 [leechers] => 20 [infohash] => 0D7EA7F06E07F56780D733F18F46DDBB826DCB65 ) )
```

And I want that seeder count into a string such as $seeds. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Sounds like you want [extract](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
$seeds = $ret['0D7EA7F06E07F56780D733F18F46DDBB826DCB65']['seeders'];
```

Answer (score 0):

you can user `strval()` to convert a number to a string.

`$string = strval($number);`

or you can cast it into a string:

`$string = (string)$number;`

in your context that would be:

`$string = strval($ret['0D7EA7F06E07F56780D733F18F46DDBB826DCB65']['seeders']);`

However that odd string is also the first index of the array so you could also do it like this:

`$string = strval($ret[0]['seeders']);`

or if you want ot use only indexes ('seeders' is also the first index of the second array):

`$string = strval($ret[0][0]);`

if you just want the number then it's easy too:

`$num = $ret[0][0];`

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear if you're looking to assign the array value(s?) as a separate variable(s?) or just to cast it into a string. Here's a nice way to accomplish all the above options, by assigning each array key as a separate variable with the matching array value:

```
$ret_vars = array_pop($ret);
foreach ($ret_vars as $variable_name=>$variable_value) :
    ${$variable_name} = (string)$variable_value;
endforeach;
```

In your original example, this would end up populating `$seeders`, `$completed`, `$leechers` and `$infohash` with their matching string values. Of course, make sure these variable names are not used/needed elsewhere in the code. If that's the case, simply add some sort of unique prefix to the `${}` construct, like `${'ret_'.$variable_name}`